# Convert string like this to php array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to convert a string like this code below to array, How can I do this plz?

```
$icon = '{``font``:``feather``,``icon``:``feather-facebook``}';
```

Is there any way by using json_decode or something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: `str_replace()`  the double backtics with a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The input string is not proper json format
2. When you correct json syntax then you can just json_decode it

```
    $icon = '{"font":"feather","icon":"feather-facebook"}';
    $array = json_decode($icon);
    var_dump($array);
```